# Why is the struct unknown at compiletime in the code?

Tags: struct, d, template-meta-programming, compile-time

I was wondering how I could change the code below such the `bmBc` is computed at compile time . The one below works for runtime but it is not ideal since I need to know the  `bmBc` table at compile-time . I could appreciate advice on how I could improve on this.

```
   import std.conv:to;
   import std.stdio;

    int [string]  bmBc;
    immutable string pattern = "GCAGAGAG";
    const int size = to!int(pattern.length);
    struct king {

            void  calculatebmBc(int i)()
            {
                    static if ( i < size -1 )
                           bmBc[to!string(pattern[i])]=to!int(size-i-1);

                  //        bmBc[pattern[i]] ~= i-1;

                    calculatebmBc!(i+1)();
            }
            void calculatebmBc(int i: size-1)() {

            }
    }

    void main(){
      king myKing;

      const  int start = 0;
      myKing.calculatebmBc!(start)();
     //1.   enum  bmBcTable =  bmBc;

    }
```

Comment: Can you add full code sample? Currently: ASIZE, ALPHABET, size are unknown. Also please specify compiler version and platform. 
Most likely you have infinite recursion in calculatebmBc!(S,C,I,i+1)(pattern ,bmBc)

Comment: @sibnick ,thanks, I just edited the code, and cut it to point to my exact issue.

Answer (score 1):

The variables `bmBc` and `bmh` can't be read at compile time because you define them as regular runtime variables.

You need to define them as `enum`s, or possibly `immutable`, to read them at compile time, but that also means that you cannot modify them after initialization. You need to refactor your code to return values instead of using out parameters.

Alternatively, you can initialize them at runtime inside of a module constructor.

Comment: I just edited the code to clearly re-state my challenge. Am sorry for being ambiguous .

Comment: @Walker The answer still stands. `bmBc` is a global runtime mutable variable; the compiler doesn't know its value, especially because the recursive call to `calculatebmBc` modifies it at runtime.